# Water dripping from the ceiling over a humidifier

Tags: ceiling, leak, moisture

Humidity in my house right now 13%, which is normal during winter. I have cathedral ceilings with no attic. It is an older, very large, 100% wood house, log cabin style. I ran 1 gallon humidifier for a week and now have water dripping exactly above the  humidifier. It drips like one drop every 10 min at night and more often during day time. It is 21F outside. The roofer had said the roof is fine.  Is it because of the humidifier? But the house is huge and I would think the moisture would spread around the house, not accumulate somewhere. The distance between the floor and the ceiling is also substantial. What is happening, please help.

Comment: Moisture doesn't spread around the house (at least not quickly) unless air spreads around the house. What type of heating system do you have? What is the water condensing on? More information, please.

Comment: @isherwood it is a heat furnace, almost brand new.

Comment: @isherwood Forced Air heating system.

Comment: Think maybe a cold spot on ceiling, less/no insulation in that spot.  Does moving the humidifier move the dripping?

Comment: Probably condensation from the humidifier, how well insulated?  How tall a ceiling? To diagnose, can you simply turn off the humidifier for a couple of days and see if the problem goes away?  If so, "there's your clue".

Comment: @crip659 as soon as I discovered the drip I turned the humidifier off. So it is off for a week now, but the dripping continues from ONE SPOT ONLY. The insulation is proper according to the roofer.  I don't know how tall a ceiling, but the house is 3 story high with open areas. It drips in the open area. Sorry, I am a female and can't explain any better,

Comment: Do you get snow where you're at? Are there vents in your roof? I've had snow blow into the vents and then melt inside the attic, causing it to drop from the ceiling.

Comment: Quite a few males would also have trouble explaining.  With humidifier off for a week and still dripping, think it is time for another roofer or similar person.

Comment: @PhilippNagel There is snow outside. No snow on the roof. The roofer has 30 years experience. He said to figure it out I have to wait for the summer time. No attic in the house. Probably no vents. All was fine until I ran humidifier for a week.

Comment: @crip659 It drips one drop at the time from one spot only.

Comment: Did you have a good warm up outside that melted the snow on roof or is roof like an A frame and snow does not collect on it?

Comment: @crip659 No warm ups, 21F during day time, no snow on the A frame roof

Answer (score 3):

**I bet your ceiling is cold.**

Consider my cold drink on a hot day.  Humidity has spread around the clubhouse.  The outside of my glass is dripping wet and I must use a coaster.  Why does the humidity stop just on my glass and not breeze on by?  It is because my glass is cold, and passing humidity that bumps into it condenses into water.

So too your roof.  You have a cold spot for whatever reason.  Ambient humidity in the house stops there and condenses.  You could try to address the spot, or give up on humidifying the great room and concentrate on humidifying bedrooms.

Comment: But even with a humidifier running non stop for a week, overall humidity in the house won't reach even 25%. This is the first time in my 10 years living in the house.  New roof-6 years ago.

Comment: Think this is more roof/space under roof problem than humidifier problem.  Some snow has probably gotten in and is now melting slowly.  Humidifier was just on at wrong time, snow started melting.  If want can turn it on again, will not make any difference, would move so not under leak/drip.

Comment: Humidity isn't the only factor in play here. The dew point is the critical number relative to condensation. So even low humidity can produce condensation when the air strikes a surface area with a temp at the dew point or below. But I'm with @crip659 the humidifier may not be the problem.

Comment: @crip659 How some snow can get in (where?), if it is A shape roof with no attic? Inside beams support the cathedral ceiling. And it drips from one spot only.

Comment: You can figure it out pretty quick.  Turn off the humidifier and see if it keeps dripping.

Comment: Right direction of wind blowing when snowing out. snow can get into tiny opening if wind blowing right.  If ceiling is painted, bet that one spot has a very tiny hole in the paint.

Comment: There should some empty space between the insulation and roof deck, maybe only inch or two, and should be vent on peak or just below peak on sides and another vent at bottom.  Roofer can tell you where vents are, they probably not be big and blend in with roof looks.

Comment: @crip659 I will post an update. It is going to snow heavily for the next 2 days. The humidifier is off.

Answer (score 3):

After all it was the humidifier. One week non stop moist stream toward the ceiling did create the described scenario. It took a long time for the dripping to stop.

Comment: I moved my bathroom fan to above the shower, and I have no attic entrance so I used the hole from the old fan to get up and do the work.  It made it hard to properly insulate.  During showers in the winter, water droplets form and drip in that area because it wasn't insulated properly.

Comment: Thanks for posting the followup!